# addEventListener not working. error says main2.js:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null at main2.js:1

Tags: javascript

```js
let carts = document.querySelectorAll('.add-cart');

let products = [
    {
        name:'Heinz Beanz',
        tag: 'heinzbeans',
        price: 2.55,
        inCart: 0
    },
    {
        name:'brown Beanz',
        tag: 'brownbeans',
        price: 2.55,
        inCart: 0
    },
    {
        name:'white Beanz',
        tag: 'whitebeans',
        price: 2.55,
        inCart: 0
    },
    {
        name:'black Beanz',
        tag: 'blackbeans',
        price: 2.55,
        inCart: 0
    },
    {
        name:'red Beanz',
        tag: 'redbeans',
        price: 2.55,
        inCart: 0
    }
];



for (let i=0; i < carts.length; i++) {
    carts[i].addEventListener('click', () => {
        cartNumbers(products[i]);
    })
}
function onLoadCartNumbers() {
    let productNumbers = localStorage.getItem('cartNumbers');

    if(productNumbers) {
        document.querySelector('.cart span').textContent = productNumbers;
    }
}
function cartNumbers(product) {
    
    let productNumbers = localStorage.getItem('cartNumbers');
    
    productNumbers = parseInt(productNumbers);
     
    if (productNumbers) {
        localStorage.setItem('cartNumbers', productNumbers + 1);
        document.querySelector('.cart span').textContent = productNumbers + 1;
    } else {
        localStorage.setItem('cartNumbers', 1);
        document.querySelector('.cart span').textContent = 1;
    }
    setItems(product);
     
 }

 function setItems(product) {
    let cartItems = localStorage.getItem('productsInCart');
    cartItems = JSON.parse(cartItems);
    console.log("My cartItems are", cartItems);
    
    if (cartItems !=null) {
        if (cartItems[product.tag] == undefined) {
            cartItems = {
                ...cartItems,
                [product.tag]: product
            }
        }

    

        cartItems[product.tag].inCart += 1;


    } else {
        product.inCart = 1;
        cartItems = {
            [product.tag]: product
        }


    
    
    }

    
    localStorage.setItem("productsInCart", JSON.stringify(cartItems));
 }
 onLoadCartNumbers();
```

```html
<body>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar">
            <div class="logo">
                <a href="#">MARCHÉ THAI</a>
            </div>
            <div class="navbar_items">
                <ul>
                    
                    <li><a href="{% url 'main_page-home'%}"><i class='fas fa-home'></i>Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#contact_us">Contact Us</a></li>
                    
                    <li class= "carts">
                        <a href="#"><i class='fa fa-shopping-cart'>
                        </i>Cart <span>0</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Check Out</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            </div>
            <div class="container2">

                <div class="image">
                    <img src="{% static 'main_page/maincss/images/beans101.jpg' %}" width="200" height="200" alt="blah">
                    <h3>Beans</h3>
                    <h3>$2.55</h3>
                    <a class="add-cart cart1" href="#">Add Cart</a>
                    
                </div>
                
                <div class="image">
                    <img src="{% static 'main_page/maincss/images/beans102.jpg'%}"  width="200" height="200" alt="blah">
                    <h3>Beans</h3>
                    <h3>$2.55</h3>
                    <a class="add-cart cart2" href="#">Add Cart</a>
                    
                </div>   
                <div class="image">
                    <img src="{% static 'main_page/maincss/images/beans101.jpg' %}" width="200" height="200" alt="blah">
                    <h3>Beans</h3>
                    <h3>$2.55</h3>
                    <a class="add-cart cart3" href="#">Add Cart</a>
                   
                </div>   
                <div class="image">
                    <img src="{% static 'main_page/maincss/images/beans102.jpg'%}" width="200" height="200"
                    alt="blah">
                    <h3>Beans</h3>
                    <h3>$2.55</h3>
                    <a class="add-cart cart4" href="#">Add Cart</a>
                    
                </div>   
                <div class="image">
                    <img src="{% static 'main_page/maincss/images/beans101.jpg' %}" width="200" height="200"
                    alt="blah">
                    <h3>Beans</h3>
                    <h3>$2.55</h3>
                    <a class="add-cart cart5" href="#">Add Cart</a>
                   
                </div>  
            </div>
            
            </div>         
         

            
         

            
           
        <div class="footer">
            <a href="#">@ 2020 MARCHÉ THAI</a>
        </div>
    </div>


</body>
```

`addEventListener` is not working. Error says:

> main2.js:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null at main2.js:1

JavaScript:

```js
let carts = document.querySelectorAll('.add-cart');
    
let products = [
    {
        name:'Heinz Beanz',
        tag: 'heinzbeans',
        price: 2.55,
        inCart: 0
    },
    {
        name:'brown Beanz',
        tag: 'brownbeans',
        price: 2.55,
        inCart: 0
    },
    {
        name:'white Beanz',
        tag: 'whitebeans',
        price: 2.55,
        inCart: 0
    },
    {
        name:'black Beanz',
        tag: 'blackbeans',
        price: 2.55,
        inCart: 0
    },
    {
        name:'red Beanz',
        tag: 'redbeans',
        price: 2.55,
        inCart: 0
    }
];

for (let i=0; i < carts.length; i++) {
    carts[i].addEventListener('click', () => {
        cartNumbers(products[i]);
    })
}
```

I've also tried:

```js
document.getElementById("carts").addEventListener("click", () => {
  alert("You clicked?");
});
```

Which hasn't worked either and I still receive an error.

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null  at main2.js:1

Comment: Try console.log(carts). It must be an array of the DOM elements.

Comment: you should validate that your selector is not an empty array first. Also try to use the selector on the developer tools console to verify that you are selecting the right Nodes.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is probably in your first line, try to run this in the console of your page:

```
document.querySelectorAll('.add-cart')
```

Do you get null or an array of elements?

Post your html if you can't find the right selector to get your elements

Comment: If `carts` were null, it would throw a different error.

Comment: i've shared the complete code, as I was debugging the code, I noticed, it would'nt run behond the addEventListener

Answer (score 0):

The following code doesn't work because 'carts' in your html is defined as class, it's fine if you try to change it top 'id'

```
document.getElementById("carts").addEventListener("click", () => {
alert("You clicked?");
});
```

And to check the ".addEventListner" i've tried 'alert' messages, seems they are working, you can click on any "Add Cart" button to see the message.,

```js
let carts = document.querySelectorAll('.add-cart');
    
let products = [
    {
        name:'Heinz Beanz',
        tag: 'heinzbeans',
        price: 2.55,
        inCart: 0
    },
    {
        name:'brown Beanz',
        tag: 'brownbeans',
        price: 2.55,
        inCart: 0
    },
    {
        name:'white Beanz',
        tag: 'whitebeans',
        price: 2.55,
        inCart: 0
    },
    {
        name:'black Beanz',
        tag: 'blackbeans',
        price: 2.55,
        inCart: 0
    },
    {
        name:'red Beanz',
        tag: 'redbeans',
        price: 2.55,
        inCart: 0
    }
];

for (let i=0; i < carts.length; i++) {
    carts[i].addEventListener('click', () => {
        // cartNumbers(products[i]);
        alert('Test message :' + i);
    })
}

document.getElementById("carts").addEventListener("click", () => {
    alert("You clicked?");
  });
```

```html
<body>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar">
            <div class="logo">
                <a href="#">MARCHÉ THAI</a>
            </div>
            <div class="navbar_items">
                <ul>
                    
                    <li><a href="{% url 'main_page-home'%}"><i class='fas fa-home'></i>Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#contact_us">Contact Us</a></li>
                    
                    <li id= "carts">
                        <a href="#"><i class='fa fa-shopping-cart'>
                        </i>Cart <span>0</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Check Out</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            </div>
            <div class="container2">

                <div class="image">
                    <img src="{% static 'main_page/maincss/images/beans101.jpg' %}" width="200" height="200" alt="blah">
                    <h3>Beans</h3>
                    <h3>$2.55</h3>
                    <a class="add-cart cart1" href="#">Add Cart</a>
                    
                </div>
                
                <div class="image">
                    <img src="{% static 'main_page/maincss/images/beans102.jpg'%}"  width="200" height="200" alt="blah">
                    <h3>Beans</h3>
                    <h3>$2.55</h3>
                    <a class="add-cart cart2" href="#">Add Cart</a>
                    
                </div>   
                <div class="image">
                    <img src="{% static 'main_page/maincss/images/beans101.jpg' %}" width="200" height="200" alt="blah">
                    <h3>Beans</h3>
                    <h3>$2.55</h3>
                    <a class="add-cart cart3" href="#">Add Cart</a>
                   
                </div>   
                <div class="image">
                    <img src="{% static 'main_page/maincss/images/beans102.jpg'%}" width="200" height="200"
                    alt="blah">
                    <h3>Beans</h3>
                    <h3>$2.55</h3>
                    <a class="add-cart cart4" href="#">Add Cart</a>
                    
                </div>   
                <div class="image">
                    <img src="{% static 'main_page/maincss/images/beans101.jpg' %}" width="200" height="200"
                    alt="blah">
                    <h3>Beans</h3>
                    <h3>$2.55</h3>
                    <a class="add-cart cart5" href="#">Add Cart</a>
                   
                </div>  
            </div>
            
            </div>         
         

            
         

            
           
        <div class="footer">
            <a href="#">@ 2020 MARCHÉ THAI</a>
        </div>
    </div>


</body>
```

Comment: cool thanks, I see it works here but in my browser its not working, i've tried with google chrome and Microsoft edge. And in both browsers, in developer tools no message appears when I click on add cart. :(